# UITableviewcell.accessoryview touchDown?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

On the UITableviewCell.accessoryview I would like to have the `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method be called on the touchUpInside action. Any ideas on how to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend setting the table view cell's `accessoryView` property to a custom `UIButton` instance and then setting a custom selector to handle whatever touch event you want to do: (*this code is not tested, FYI*)

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(actionSelector) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

You can replace `actionSelector` with a custom selector of your choice and `UIControlEventTouchDown` with whatever event flag you desire, such as `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` ([more details for action selectors](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl)).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such in-built "Touch Down" method.

And TouchUpInside would automatically call accessoryButtonTapped method.

You may try some custom work around for that but I am not sure how efficient it would be and how you would be able to customize it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the information... I may not need to do what I'm trying.